# If $A$ is c.e.-complete then the join of $A$ and $A^c$ isn't c.e

Tags: computability

Let $A\subseteq\{0, 1\}^∗$, and let $A^c = \{0, 1\}^∗ \setminus A$ be the complement of $A$. Prove: If A is $\le_m$-complete for CE, then $A$ join $A^c$ is neither c.e. nor co-c.e.

c.e --> Computably enumerable

The join of two languages $A, B \subseteq \{0, 1\}^∗$ is defined by: $\{x0 \mid x\in A\} \cup \{y1 \mid y \in B\}$.

Comment: what is m-complete here?

Comment: Probably completeness with respect to computable many-one reductions.

Comment: Oh man...i figured this out before I saw these solutions. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be $A$ join $A^c$, for the concept of *join* defined in your question.
Consider the language $H = \{\langle T \rangle \, \mid \, \text{$T$ is a Turing Machine that halts on empty input}\}$.

Let $f$ be $m$-reduction from $H$ to $A$.
Given word $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ (think of this word as a Turing Machine), $w \in H \iff f(w) \in A \iff f(w)0 \in B$. Similarly, $w \not\in H \iff f(w) \not\in A \iff f(w)1 \in B$.

Suppose towards a contradiction that $B \in \mathsf{CE}$.
Construct a Turing machine $M^*$ that simulates, in parallel, two executions of a Turing Machine $M$ that recognizes $B$ until one of them halts and accepts. One execution of $M$ has input $f(w)0$ and the other has input $f(w)1$.
If $M(f(w)0)$ halts and accepts then $M^*$ accepts.
If $M(f(w)1)$ halts and accepts, then  $M^*$ rejects.

Since $f(w)0 \in B \iff f(w)1 \not\in B$, at least one of $M(f(w)0)$ and $M(f(w)1)$ eventually halts and accepts. This shows that $M^*$ decides $H$ and provides the sought contradiction ($H$ is a well-known undecidable language).

Suppose towards a contradiction that $B \in \mathsf{\text{co-CE}}$.
Construct a Turing machine $\overline{M}^*$ that simulates, in parallel, two executions of a Turing Machine $\overline{M}$ that recognizes $\overline{B}$ until one of them halts and accepts. One execution of $\overline{M}$ has input $f(w)0$ and the other has input $f(w)1$.
If $\overline{M}(f(w)0)$ halts and accepts then $\overline{M}^*$ rejects.
If $\overline{M}(f(w)1)$ halts and accepts, then  $\overline{M}^*$ accepts.

Since $f(w)0 \in \overline{B} \iff f(w)1 \not\in \overline{B}$, at least one of $\overline{M}(f(w)0)$ and $\overline{M}(f(w)1)$ eventually halts and accepts. This shows that $\overline{M}^*$ decides $H$ and provides the sought contradiction.

Therefore we must have $B \not\in \mathsf{CE}$ and $B \not\in \mathsf{\text{co-CE}}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for example, that $A$ join $A^c$ is c.e. Since $A$ is c.e.-complete, $A$ join $A^c$ reduces to $A$. In particular, $A^c$ reduces to $A$. Show that this leads to a contradiction.

The proof that $A$ join $A^c$ isn't co-c.e. is similar.